# Referring to individuals while building a list in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm working on a BMI calculator in Python. The goal is to prompt the user to enter the height and weight of six people already in a list, calculate their BMI with that data, and then return the results, mentioning each person by name and then giving their BMI and weight category.

I have the list and the prompt to enter height and weight figured out, as well as the formula for calculating each individual BMI, and the weight categories work as intended. However, I can't seem to get the final readout to use each person's name. It only ever displays the last name on the list, basically returning the needed values but assigning them all to one person. How do I get the readout to show the proper people for each result? Code is below:

```py
#First things first, let's get the names
name_list = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Dave', 'Erica', 'Fiona']
y = 1
#For each name in the list, we'll also need to store their height and weight.
height_list = []
weight_list = []
bmi_list = []
underweight = 0
normal_weight = 0
overweight = 0
for name in name_list:
    print("Current subject is: ", name)
    height = int(input("Enter height in inches: ",))
    height_list.append(height)
    weight = int(input("Enter weight in pounds: ",))
    weight_list.append(weight)
#Now we display the person's name, BMI, and their weight category.    
for i in range(0, len(weight_list)) :
        bmi_list.append(weight_list[i] * 703 / height_list[i]**2)
for i in bmi_list:
    if i < 18.5 :
        underweight = underweight + 1
        print(name, "is underweight")
    elif i >= 18.5 and i < 25 :
        normal_weight = normal_weight + 1
        print(name, "is normal weight")
    elif i >= 25 :
        overweight = overweight + 1
        print (name, "is overweight")


print("Final Report: ")
print("The total number of underweight individuals is ", underweight)
print("The total number of normal weight individuals are ", normal_weight)
print("The total number of overweight individuals are ", overweight)
```

Everything seems to work, but each of the six results is assigned to Fiona, as opposed to the first result being for Alice, the second for Bob, and so on. I'm pretty sure the solution is simple, but I've fiddled around with this code for hours and haven't been able to fix it. Thoughts?

Comment: in this for loop `for name in name_list:` the variable `name` is set to `"Fiona"` at last. So `print(name, "is underweight")` will show Fiona.

Comment: An unrelated change you might want to consider is to cast the input for `height` and `weight` respectively using `float` rather than `int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`name` is defined in the first `for` loop, and is lastly updated to the last element in `name_list`, `'Fiona'`.

In the last `for` loop, where you iterator over `bmi_list`, `name` is not updated.

One approach is to iterate over the indexes, and extract the name and bmi for each index:

```py
for i in range(0, len(bmi_list)):
    name = name_list[i]
    bmi = bmi_list[i]
    if bmi < 18.5 :
        underweight = underweight + 1
        print(name, "is underweight")
    elif bmi >= 18.5 and bmi < 25 :
        normal_weight = normal_weight + 1
        print(name, "is normal weight")
    elif bmi >= 25 :
        overweight = overweight + 1
        print (name, "is overweight")
```

Comment: That seems to have worked, for the most part. I get the proper names for each value, but now it seems like each BMI only returns as "underweight", even though I've made sure to enter overweight values. Does this loop overwrite the list somehow?

Comment: @PenDragon did you notice the conditions should now use `bmi` and not `i`?

Comment: I did not! Amending "i" to "bmi" worked perfectly. Sometimes I need an extra set of eyes. This worked exactly like it's supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You need to iterate over `name` as well.

Long answer: at the end of the first loop, `for name in name_list`, the last `name` is "fiona", so everytime you refer to `name` after this loops ends, "fiona" is stored under `name`. When you call `print(name, "is underweight")`, `name` is "fiona".

How to fix:
You need to iterate both over `bmi_list` and `name_list`. A good practice is using `zip`:

```
for i, name in zip(bmi_list, name_list):
    # this loop iterates both over `bmi_list` and `name_list`
    if i < 18.5 :
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simply because you are not iterating over the name_list.

Replace:

```
for i in bmi_list:
    if i < 18.5 :
        underweight = underweight + 1
        print(name, "is underweight")
    elif i >= 18.5 and i < 25 :
        normal_weight = normal_weight + 1
        print(name, "is normal weight")
    elif i >= 25 :
        overweight = overweight + 1
        print (name, "is overweight")
```

With:

```
for i in range(len(bmi_list)):
    if bmi_list[i] < 18.5 :
        underweight = underweight + 1
        print(name_list[i], "is underweight")
    elif bmi_list[i] >= 18.5 and bmi_list[i] < 25 :
        normal_weight = normal_weight + 1
        print(name_list[i], "is normal weight")
    elif bmi_list[i] >= 25 :
        overweight = overweight + 1
        print (name_list[i], "is overweight")
```

Also, not too sure why you would want to use int() for height in inches, but that's your call ;)

Answer (score 0):

After you iterate through all of the names, `name` is still the last of those names: you never again change it to match the person you're examining.

```
for i in bmi_list:
    if i < 18.5 :
        underweight = underweight + 1
        print(name, "is underweight")
```

Instead, you have to use the index that matches each person.

```
for idx, bmi in enumerate(bmi_list):
    if bmi < 18.5 :
        underweight = underweight + 1
        print(name_list[idx], "is underweight")
```